# django - 404 error reporting

Tags: python, django

I have set 404 error reporting on Django 1.6 by adding, `django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware` at `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`. I have placed it first since some of other middleware classes may interrupt. However, I am not receiving 404 errors.

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS =
EMAIL_HOST =
EMAIL_HOST_USER =
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD =
EMAIL_PORT =
```

Above are my email setting and have been tested.

It is annoying since on my local environment one of generic views is working however not on production and I just receive 404 without knowing the actual error.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Those are obviously not your email settings.  What is your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django emailing on errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589124/django-emailing-on-errors)

Comment: @garnertb I have appropriate values defined against each of the email setting. My question is that I am not receiving 404 error emails.

Comment: Also, I have defined ADMINS and MANAGERS and also EMAIL_BACKEND. So this question is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589124/django-emailing-on-errors

Comment: Those are relevant settings that you need to include in the question.

Comment: Does your DEBUG=False?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68145/discussion-between-codingmehelp-and-garnertb).

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, Django will only send broken link emails when `DEBUG=False` and `BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware` appears before other middleware that intercepts 404 errors.  So ensure that `django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware` is first in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` tuple. If you have both of those settings correct, ensure that you can send an email using Django's `mail_managers` function (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/#mail-managers) via the Django shell.

Comment: I ran mail_managers function through shell and got this message;     **% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting MANAGERS, but set
tings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO
_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.**

Comment: Didn't understand why was the question given -1. This question is not a duplicate nor did the answer given helped in anyway.

Comment: ok. I guess someone was feeling funny today. Thanks for your help so far.